# Having difficulties placing a frame within a frame with Tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am having issues trying to place a frame within a frame using classes/objects with python/tkinter. My goal is to simply place a frame in the north west corner of the outer frame instead of the whole window itself. I think I'm incorrectly referencing the outer frame in the inner frame class but I'm not 100% sure. I am fairly new to OOP and tkinter so forgive my ignorance and I appreciate the help.

Sample code:

```
from tkinter import *

class window():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master.minsize(500, 500)
        master.maxsize(500,500)

        self.outer_frame = Frame(master, width = 250, height = 250, bg = "red").place(anchor = CENTER, relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5)
    def create_inner_window(self):
        self.inner_frame = inner_frame(self.outer_frame)

class inner_frame():
    def __init__(self, outer_frame):
        self.inner_frame = Frame(master = outer_frame, width = 125, height = 125, bg = "blue").place(anchor = NW)

root = Tk()
my_window = window(root)
my_window.create_inner_window()
root.mainloop()
```

What I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

What I get instead:

[image]

Comment: `self.outer_frame` is `None` because it is the result of `place(...)`.  Separate `self.outer_frame = Frame(...).place(...)` into two statements.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked. Thanks, you were a really big help!